# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)

Tags: php

Tenho essa function:

```
public function showCredentialsPhoto(){
        if (isset($_SESSION["logado"]) && $_SESSION["logado"] === TRUE && (!empty($_SESSION['avatar']))):
            echo "<img class='nav-user-photo' src='<?php echo $_SESSION['avatar'];?>'/>";
        else: 
            echo "<img class='nav-user-photo' src='galeria/sistema/user.png'>";
        endif;
    }
```

Mas quando chamo ela dá erro:

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp\class.User.php on line 196

Porque? Como posso corrigir isso?

A linha 196 é essa:

```
echo "<img class='nav-user-photo' src='<?php echo $_SESSION['avatar'];?>'/>";
```

Comment: Você tem um código PHP em uma *string* no PHP? PHP inception.

Comment: PHP o que? Inception?? @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: É um código php numa página php. Todo meu código é isso

Comment: Ainda tá com o erro @MarceloBoni. O mesmo

Comment: o *Inception* foi uma piada fazendo referência ao filme Inception, que as pessoas entram no sonho do sonho do sonho... Espero que não tenha entendido mal e veja se a resposta foi clara o suficiente.

Answer (score 3):

O problema está em basicamente utilizar um código PHP dentro de um texto no PHP. Você definiu o texto com aspas duplas e isso informa ao PHP para interpretar seu conteúdo. O que isso significa? Que se houver uma variável do PHP dentro da *string* ele tentará a substituir pelo seu respectivo valor. Você fez:

```
echo "<img class='nav-user-photo' src='<?php echo $_SESSION['avatar'];?>'/>";
```

E `$_SESSION` é uma variável do PHP, então ele tenta substituir por seu valor. Neste caso, o valor seria um *array*, o que já complica em substituir o valor de um *array* dentro de uma *string*, mas logo após você utiliza `['avatar']`, com o objetivo de informar qual o valor do *array* que você deseja. Neste caso, a sintaxe se torna inválida, o PHP não consegue interpretar corretamente e dispara o erro citado. Para tal, quando você precisará acessar uma determinada posição de um *array* dentro de uma *string*, você precisará fazer isso entre chaves (`{}`). Desta forma, você informa ao PHP que o que está dentro das chaves deve ser analisado em conjunto e, assim, o PHP entenderá que o que você precisa é acessar a chave `avatar` do *array* `$_SESSION`.

O correto seria:

```
echo "<img class='nav-user-photo' src='{$_SESSION['avatar']}'/>";
```

Perceba que o código PHP dentro da *string* é desnecessário e não funcionará. Mesmo que não desse erro, seu HTML estaria errado, pois o código PHP interno iria ser enviado como texto. Ou faça a solução acima, utilizando as chaves, ou você pode utilizar o operador de concatenação:

```
echo "<img class='nav-user-photo' src='" . $_SESSION['avatar'] . "'/>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Estás utilizando incorretamente as concatenações de string.

Veja o que estás fazendo na linha:

```
echo "<img class='nav-user-photo' src='<?php echo $_SESSION['avatar'];?>'/>";
```

Dentro do `echo` você está abrindo uma `tag` `PHP` para dar outro `echo`, quando deveria fazer algo como:

```
echo "<img class='nav-user-photo' src=" . $_SESSION['avatar'] . "/>";
```

Ou

```
echo "<img class='nav-user-photo' src='{$_SESSION['avatar']}'/>";
```